# Numpy Error when trying to plot a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, genfromtxt

I am trying to plot a histogram with this code. Python is giving me an error in line 1.

```
numpy.genfromtxt('dataset1.txt', dtype=<type 'float'>,
comments='#', delimiter=None, skip_header=0,
skip_footer=0, missing_values=None,
filling_values=None, usecols=None, unpack=None)
plt.errorbar(x,y, yerr=yErr)
ls='',marker='.'
errorevery=n
numpy.polyfit(x,y,degr,w=None)
plt.xlabel('An arbitrary x-value')
plt.ylabel('A Gaussian y-value')
plt.title('One fine Gaussian')
```

Comment: Can you share the full error trace and the dataset file?

Comment: Please include your code with the imports as well as the entire error trace. On top of that: (1) Numpy is generally imported with the alias `np`. (2) `<type 'float'>` is not valid python code, which may be the cause of your error. (Though, it seems like most of your code won't do what you expect it to do...)

Comment: Do you mind sharing what that error is?

Comment: I think you've just cut&pasted a documentation on `genfromtxt`. Hence all the useless `arg=None` (that, in a documentation, means that there is an optional argument whose default value is None), hence the `dtype=<type 'float'>` which is not a python code, but a string in a documentation, meaning that by default data are treated as float. Chance are that `numpy.genfromtxt('dataset1.txt')` is what you want. But impossible to say without the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The first line produces:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.genfromtxt('dataset1.txt', dtype=<type 'float'>,
   ...: comments='#', delimiter=None, skip_header=0,
   ...: skip_footer=0, missing_values=None,
   ...: filling_values=None, usecols=None, unpack=None)
  Cell In[2], line 1
    np.genfromtxt('dataset1.txt', dtype=<type 'float'>,
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`syntax error` means it fails the first step, reading the string and figuring what it is in basic python terms.  Note the tick, `^` under '<type...>'.  This isn't valid python notation.  As comments say, it's a documenation way of saying put something like 'float' or 'int' here.

Sooner of later you need to learn basic python, and how to read documenation of functions like this.

AND write SO questions with enough information.